# MySQL select top rows with same condition values

Tags: mysql, sql, select, sql-order-by, limit

I don't know how to title this problem. Correct me if you have better words.

I have two tables, Users and Posts.

**Users:**

```
id | username | password | ...
```

**Posts:**

```
id | author_id | title | content | ...
```

Now I want to list the "most active" users - the users who have written the most posts. And specifically, I want the `top 10` result.

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS count 
FROM Posts p, Users u
WHERE u.id=p.author_id
GROUP BY p.author_id 
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

I can get the expected result. However, the ranking may not be "*fair*" if some users have same number of posts.

E.g., I may get results like:

```
User 1  | 14
User 2  | 13
...
User 9  | 4
User 10 | 4
```

Here, there are actually several more users who have `4` posts.

So, the `top 10` could be not exactly `10` results. How can I get a more "*fair*" result that contains extra rows of users who have `4` posts?

Comment: Very interesting problem :) Might need a variable in query, let's see what people come up with.

Comment: Do you mind adding some sample data so we can see some nice fiddles?

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I simplified my data here. If you want to test, you can try "top 2" case where you can easily fake some data.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the right solution, I think: you need the subquery to know how much post has the 10th place in your top ten. Then, you use the outer query to extract the users with almost that postcount.

```
SELECT u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS count 
FROM Posts p
JOIN Users u ON u.id = p.author_id
GROUP BY p.author_id 
HAVING COUNT(p.id) >= 
(
    SELECT COUNT(p.id) AS count 
    FROM Posts p
    JOIN Users u ON u.id = p.author_id
    GROUP BY p.author_id 
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 9, 1
)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: I think it should be `LIMIT 9, 1`.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! Edited

Answer (score 3):

Maybe not the best solution

```
select u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS count 
FROM Posts p
join Users u on u.id = p.author_id
GROUP BY p.author_id 
having COUNT(p.id) in 
(
    SELECT COUNT(p.id)
    FROM Posts p
    join Users u on u.id = p.author_id
    GROUP BY p.author_id 
    ORDER BY count DESC
    LIMIT 10    
)
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `HAVING COUNT(p.id) IN`? If you use `>=`, the subquery has to return a single value. You could change the  subquery to use `LIMIT 9, 1`.

Comment: You shouldn't use `DISTINCT`.

Comment: I've implemented @Barmar suggestion in my answer, I think is the right one

Comment: Tried @Jean 's answer and worked. This answer just reports "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'". My MYSQL version is 5.6.20.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT username, PostCount
FROM (SELECT username, PostCount, IF(@PostCount = @PostCount:=PostCount, @idx:=@idx+1, @Idx:=1) AS idx
      FROM (SELECT u.username, COUNT(p.id) AS PostCount 
            FROM Posts p
            INNER JOIN Users u ON u.id=p.author_id
            GROUP BY p.author_id 
           ) AS A, (SELECT @PostCount:=0, @Idx:=1) AS B
      ORDER BY PostCount DESC
     ) AS A
WHERE idx <= 10;
```

Comment: You do a subquery for each author to extract the postcount, and you try to group the user by their postcount, and I think it's a bit nonsense..